# Sort dict keys into list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing IP addresses and hd space for each IP.

{'192.168.100.102': '7.3G', '192.168.100.103': '3.5G', '192.168.100.101': '7.4G', '192.168.100.107': '17G'}

I want to take three IPs with the greatest space and put them into a list. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: not much tbh. I've found a few ways but most of them either the entire set of keys to a list or only take the greatest value. I'm new to python.

Comment: what is meant by greatest space?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The values. HD space.  I need the keys which hold the 3 greatest values.

Comment: Are they all in Gb, or do you have to deal with the difference between 500Mb and 1.0 Gb?

Comment: So far, they're all in Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice off the trailing `'G'` part from the values and convert them to `float` in the *sort key*:

```
ips = {'192.168.100.102': '7.3G', '192.168.100.103': '3.5G', '192.168.100.101': '7.4G', '192.168.100.107': '17G'}

sorted_ips = sorted(ips, key=lambda x: float(ips[x][:-1]), reverse=True)[:3]
print(sorted_ips)
# ['192.168.100.107', '192.168.100.101', '192.168.100.102']
```

Comment: Note: It is assumed all the spaces are denoted in 'G'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ips = {'192.168.100.102': '7.3G', '192.168.100.103': '3.5G', '192.168.100.101': '7.4G', '192.168.100.107': '17G'}
sorted(ips, key=ips.get)[:3]
```

Actually this doesn't work because of the G in each value, use @Moses Koledoye's answer below.

Comment: This isn't exactly correct. The sorting is done *lexicographically* not as OP wants

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a lot simpler than everything i've found so far.

Comment: I didn't even look at the key values, whoops. It's still "sorted" ;)